# When do margins render on empty inline elements?

Tags: html, css

When do margins render on empty inline elements, according to the specs, and in browsers? The following code has been tested in chrome (webkit).

This code displays no margin:

```
<p>Example <span style="margin:2em"> </span>Example</p>
```

And this code does:

```
<p>Example <span style="margin:2em"></span>Example</p>
```

I understand that in the first example, the white space is collapsed, but that should make it equivalent to the second example? So why & when?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xut7/)

Comment: This might be more likely a Webkit bug than actual spec. Firefox, Opera (pre-webkit) and IE all render both examples the same way.

Comment: Note that Chrome (since v28) is now on the [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28layout_engine%29) layout engine, not WebKit. Blink is a fork of part of WebKit, but the two have diverged noticeably at this point. This may, however, be a bug present in both layout engines, if it was present in WebKit before the fork.

Comment: @ajp15243: Indeed it is present in both layout engines.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hUYYv/1/ . Note the second case there. Adding "white-space: pre-wrap" reduces it to similar as the other two cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spec says that [whitespace should be collapsed](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model) even if an inline element begins after whitespace and starts with whitespace (i.e. the opening tag appears in the middle of whitespace as in your first `span` element):

> any space (U+0020) following another space (U+0020) — even a space before the inline, if that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or 'pre-line' — is removed.

For your first `span` element, this should result in an empty element. [An empty inline element should still generate an empty box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height), albeit with zero width since there is nothing inside, and margins should still take effect since the box is always rendered:

> Empty inline elements generate empty inline boxes, but these boxes still have margins, padding, borders and a line height, and thus influence these calculations just like elements with content.

According to Chrome's Web Inspector, it looks like it's failing to generate the box for the `span` element entirely as it collapses the space in the element into the space that comes just before it. When the `span` element is empty in the source, it generates an empty box with margins correctly. All other browsers have no trouble drawing an empty box after they perform whitespace collapsing, and the spec doesn't say anything about deleting a non-anonymous box if it was made empty by the process of whitespace collapsing, so I would say that this is a Chrome bug.

As mentioned in the comments, this issue affects the latest versions of Chrome as well, which use Blink. Blink is a fork of WebKit after all, so it's not surprising to see that most of the CSS2.1 bugs plaguing WebKit haven't been fixed in Blink yet.